# Can Firestore real time updates come out of order?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am listening for changes in the documents in a collection in Firestore in my service running in a GCE instance using Java admin SDK. I am using an `Executor` with a single thread in the query snapshot listener to ensure that the events I receive are processed serially in the order that they arrive. A representative example is as follows:

```
public class ListenerClass implements EventListener<QuerySnapshot> {
    Map<String, Object> documentMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot querySnapshot, FirestoreException error) {
        for (DocumentChange dc : querySnapshot.getDocumentChanges()) {
            switch (dc.getType()) {
            case ADDED:
            case MODIFIED:
                documentMap.put(dc.getDocument().getId(), dc.getDocument().getData());
                break;
            case REMOVED:
                documentMap.remove(dc.getDocument().getId());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class WatchService {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WatchService watchService = new WatchService();
        watchService.watch();
    }

    public void watch() {
        //Initialize Firebase and get firestore instance

        Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        ListenerClass listenerClass = new ListenerClass();
        firestore.get("collection_name").addSnapshotListener(executor, listenerClass);

        //wait
    }
}
```

I wanted to know if there is a possibility of Firestore sending the events out of order. For example, if document A was updated at time t1 and t2. Can I get document snapshot of A at time t2 before the document snapshot at time t1, if t1 and t2 are very close to each other?
I havent observed this in my tests till now. I have also not seen any mention of this kind of behaviour by other people. I just wanted to know if this is a possibility and should I take care of it in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You won't receive a snapshot of a document that appears to "undo" a change made in a previous snapshot, *from the subscriber's perspective*.

However, bear in mind that in a multi-client, massively scalable system, such as Firestore, ordering is not really possible to ensure.  If you have multiple writers all reading and updating some document at nearly the same time, you could run into consistency issues if they are not coordinated with each other.  The writers should be using [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) to ensure that their reads and writes are consistent and do not interfere with each other.  If you don't coordinate the writers, their changes could appear random from the perspective of the subscriber.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the subscriber should never see a newer snapshot followed by an older snapshot of the same document if writers take care of updating documents in a transaction. Is this understanding correct? My case is fairly simple in which writers only modify a boolean flag in the document based on a condition. In case of 2 quick updates to a document by 2 different writers - one of them setting the flag to true followed by another one setting it to false, my concern was that would there be a case of subscriber seeing a snapshot in which flag is false followed by flag as true?